# How to use asynchronous javascript code with web workers in a class

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, web-worker

I wrote a javascript class, that upon instantiation creates a web worker. Another method in this class runs the worker. I want to invoke the method running the worker and then do something afterwards asynchronously. For a better understanding I added a schematic code skeleton below.

I tried to generate and store a Promise in a class variable and then act upon it, but it seemed to be a wrong ansatz. 
Link to the [JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/secilizanu/edit?js,console,output).

```
class Task{
  constructor(){
    this.data = 0;
    //this.listen; //my idea, does not work
    this.worker = new Worker('worker.js');

    this.worker.onmessage = (function(e){
      // worker constantly emits messages
      let data = e.data.split(' ');
      // suppose message is now availabe as array
      this.data = data;

      if(data.includes("trigger")){
        //trigger signals that the heavy computation is over

        /* my idea didn't work:
        *this.listen = Promise.resolve(1);
        */
      }
    }).bind(this);
  }

  async doTask(){
    this.worker.postMessage("start computation");
    //wait for the worker to finish calculation
    /*my idea
    *await this.listen;
    */

    //do something after trigger was sent
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

perhaps something like this?

```
class Task{
  constructor(){
    this.data = 0;
    this.worker = new Worker('worker.js');
  }
  async calculation() {
    if (this.worker.onmessage === null) {
      return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.worker.onmessage = e => {
          let data = e.data.split(' ');
          // suppose message is now availabe as array
          this.data = data;

          if(data.includes("trigger")){
            this.worker.onmessage = null;
            resolve();
          }
        };
        this.worker.postMessage("start computation");
      });
    } else {
      console.log('One calc at a time please...');
    }
  }
  async doTask(){
    await this.calculation();

    //do something after trigger was sent
    return 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks promising. I'll try it out tomorrow and then report back!

Comment: The approach is good, but notice that you cannot call `calculation` multiple times concurrently with this code.

Comment: @Bergi Yeah, I did that on purpose as it seemed that's the way the OP wanted it.

Comment: …but it leads to broken promises. If that's what you really want, I'd suggest adding a `if (this.worker.onmessage != null) throw new Error("…")` in the first line of the `new Promise` executor. That way the mistaken call will get a rejected promise, instead of letting the previous promise dangle by overwriting its listener.

Comment: @Bergi Ah, fair enough; I've updated my response to reflect.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI: The actual code has some methods `calculation`, `calculation2`, ... all running on the same worker... (that would be asynchronous, ideally)

Comment: @Bergi , @Jrd I don't need to call `calculation` concurrently, rather multiple times one after the other, but I agree the `if` clause couldn't hurt. In my opinion the whole class construct works with the worker in a very ugly way...

Building on @Jrd's proposal, one might also consider creating `new Worker` and `onmessage` directly in `calculation`. Since the current construct cannot run `calculation` many times...

Comment: @patrick If you want to run multiple calculations (which you should do on the same worker, as loading a worker has considerable overhead) you'd need a queue of resolving functions, or tag your results with ids.

Comment: Implemented it. Thanks guys :)